# Beaglebone flashing of internal memory

Tags: embedded-linux, sd-card, beagleboneblack, u-boot, flashing

I am re-flashing the internal emmc on my BeagleBone Green board with a Debian image stored on the pluggable SD card.

The instructions I received are to modify the /boot/uEnv.txt file in the SD card image which must be flashed and un-comment the last line :

*cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh*

This works and flashes the internal memory as expected. What I don't understand is when I then check the /boot/uEnv.txt file when the image is flashed, the line is then commented out again. Shouldn't this file be the same? What causes the file to change again when it is flashed?

How could I copy an image with this eEnv.txt file already changed to give to some one else so that it will automatically flash for them? Thanks

Comment: Do you have two u-boot? I mean if your eMMC is the first from the boot stage. is It possible your use the old version with the commented line to flash your flash?

Comment: @Initerworker , just one u-boot from my understanding. This is the BeagleBone in its initial state when first opened, and also a default Debian image from its site that I am re-flashing. I thought that the u-boot currently on the board would also get over-written with the new one?

Comment: For me, I don't see an available reason that u-boot changes your file of one line comment. So, I think you will need to debug. My first opinion is that you have two different uEnv.txt. Makes sure, you don't have **multiple** uEnv.txt, first. So, I guess it's a little miss configuration or interpretation. But I don't have your current setup and environment. If you don't think so, could you tell us more about your environment?